# SQL - Creating a table to produce a list of tables which contain more than 10 columns?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Bit stuck, been playing around sql finding tables with a count of more than 1000 rows in each, names longer than 20 characters long etc but ive gone blank.

this is my current entry to find names longer than 20 characters long, I need to modify it to show the tables that have more than 10 columns in them.

(Bit I need to change is at the bottom)

```
USE DW_Foundation

DECLARE @TableName varchar(255) 

Drop Table #Temp

Create Table #Temp (TableName Varchar(50), [Count] bigint)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 

WHERE table_type = 'base table' and table_name like 'BDR_%'

OPEN TableCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

 BEGIN 

 Declare @SQL Varchar(max)

 Set @SQL = 'Insert Into #Temp'
Set @SQL = @SQL +  ' Select ''' + @TableName + ''' as [table], count(1)as    count from ' + @TableName

EXEC (@SQL)


FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName 

END 

Select * from #Temp ((This bit here, where...?))


CLOSE TableCursor 

DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Comment: Im pretty new to SQL, it was a suggested tag sorry, should it just be tagged SQL?

Comment: (1) get row counts from sys.partitions, not by scanning entire tables. (2) you don't need a cursor for any of this. You want `select object_name(object_id), count(*) from sys.columns group by object_id having count(*) > 10`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, mark sinkinson showed the answer using the same logic as you and it worked perfectly, i'll go over it to make sure I understand it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cursors are not a good way to do this...

You should also use the `sys` tables rather than the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

The following gets all tables with a name longer than 20 characters and more than 10 columns:

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(*) AS columns 
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE LEN(t.name) > 20
GROUP BY t.name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you, i'll accept answer when I can in 5 mins

Comment: Like Aaron says, rows are in `sys.partitions`, but I'll let you work that out now that you have a start on it :-)